# ArcGIS 10 Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I'm new to GIS in general and field calculator in particular.

I have a basic attribute table with three columns. I'd like to assign values to column C based on what is in column A. If Column A = 8 then I need column C to read "pine forest". Column C is set for text with length=100 so that should not be a problem.

I had thought I could do this by selecting all of the records where column A = 8 and then using field calculator in column C to assign them the label "pine forest". However this results in an error message saying that the calculated value is invalid because it is either too large or because it is a string, which are both wrong.

Comment: If you want to assign a string, make sure your column is defined as text

Comment: Thanks, it is defined as text though.

Comment: Are you enclosing "pine forest" in quotes?

Comment: Nope, though I did try to do that and it didn't matter.

Comment: it might be helpful to post a sample of your table, or a screen capture of the field calculator for people to see if there is a syntax problem

Comment: Show your exact field calculator syntax in case you are missing something small in the expression

Comment: Hey, I restarted my computer and now it's working when I use the quotes. Thanks so much everyone! I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are encountering this error:

[image]

You need to enclose your new text in quotes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try switching to Python parser and using single quotes. Generally, I find Python much more stable while doing field calculations.